# Showing dynamic div below each on the click of item of corresponding row using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have different tiles (3 in each row to be shown) dynamically. On the click of each tile a div should shown below the corresponding row only. All these tiles are created dynamically.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoOJt.png)

Comment: please provide more details on your code and clarify what's you question exactly.

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei , I have to create a dynamic layout with three image cards in each 
row. But on the click of each images, one div should be shown below the corresponding row. E.g. If the image of Row1 is clicked then the div should be shown below Row1.
I have to use bootstrap, if I iterate using "col-md-4", Then I can show only three images in each row. But how to insert a div below each row dynamically is where I am stuck.